# Troubleshooting a Python Code Error: 'Wrong device id!'" - Shelly Cloud API

Tags: python

I consistently receive the following error: `{'isok': False, 'errors': {'wrong_device_id': 'Wrong device id!'}}`. I have tried using both HEX and decimal numbers for the "`device id`" as specified in the app, but the error persists. Additionally, I have attempted to use **`curl -X POST`**, but I am unable to even get past the authorization phase there.

```py
# Import the requests module
import requests

# Set the URL for the request
url = "https://********.shelly.cloud/device/relay/control"

# Set the headers for the request
headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer ******",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

# Set the data for the request
data = {
    "channel": "0", # The channel to turn off
    "turn": "off", # The desired state (off)
    "id": "*******" # The ID of the device (Tried both, HEX and DEC versions of device ID)
}

# Send the POST request and store the response
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)

# Print the response JSON
print(response.json())
```

Tried the same from [Shelly API Cloud Documentation](https://shelly-api-docs.shelly.cloud/cloud-control-api/communication#controlling-device-output-channels) with `curl`.